# How do I change the namespace of the classes I am using based on an input parameter?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I need to process an input xml using one of two namespaces depending on whether a value in the xml has a test or live flag.  The namespaces contain classes that are virtually identical.  So far I have not been able to do this without writing 2 entire classes that are identical except for the namespace in use.

I have seen some solutions to this in other programming languages using interfaces that return different types.  I don't see how this is possible in C#.

```
using wsdlns = MyCompany.MyLibrary.DevelopmentWSDL;
.
.
.
public void ProcessXml(XmlToProcess xml)
{
   if(xml.live == 1)
   {
       wsdlns = MyCompany.MyLibrary.ProductionWSDL;
   }
   wsdlns.ProcessingClass processingObject = new wsdlns.ProcessingClass();
.
.
.
}
```

The above code comes back with a "MyCompany.MyLibrary.ProductionWSDL is a namespace but is used like a variable error".

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The namespace of a class is set at compile time and cannot be changed dynamically.  An XML Namespace is an entirely different thing. You can dynamically play games with those all you want.

Comment: I'm thinking more that changing the type conditionally, e.g. from MyCompany.MyLibrary.DevelopmentWSDL.ProcessingClass to MyCompany.MyLibrary.ProductionWSDL.ProcessingClass is how to solve this problem, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to change the namespace at run-time, and there is no dynamic solution to it, and I don't believe there will ever be in the future.

You can handle this at `MyLibrary` level.
instead of having two different namespaces for development and production, you will need to combine them into one namespace. and from the code, you can use regular if statement to switch between them.

Or Better yet, use [preprocessor directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/)  which are design are designed for this kind of purpose. It will help the compile to know which part you need to be compiled on Debug mode, and which one to be on Release mode.

for instance, in your case `#if` and `#define` preprocessors can be used. For instance, for the development class  you do this :

```
#define DEVELOPMENT 
using System; 
//... rest of the class
```

you do also the same for the production.

Then, you can use `#if`

```
#if (DEBUG && DEVELOPMENT)
    //Some code here will only run on Debug mode only.
#else
   //Run the production version
#endif
```

Comment: Has to be dynamic, but by making another class identical to the first one except pointing the wsdlns alias to the production namespace, I can run the if in the statement that implements the class. Kind of like what you're saying about combining into one namespace.